# MySQL error near syntax 'CREATE TABLE user_bans...'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on my database that used to work fine until recently, here I keep getting the following error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE user_bans ( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, user INT NOT' at line 34`, the code is below. I did my best to fix it and find answers, but none of them helped.

```sql
-- Create 'users' table
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    nickname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, -- Unlike the 'username' field, this one is NOT unique
    email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    email_verified TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    email_verified_time INT DEFAULT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    register_ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    profile_image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, -- Set a random one when creating

    -- Ranks
    admin TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    beta_tester TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,

    -- Options
    profile_nsfw TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    profile_private TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,

    -- Moderation
    deleted TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    banned TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,

    -- Time fields
    time_registered INT NOT NULL, -- Set to current UNIX timestamp when creating
    time_last_seen INT NOT NULL -- Set to current UNIX timestamp when going offline
);

-- Create 'user_bans' table
CREATE TABLE user_bans (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user INT NOT NULL,
    banned_by INT NOT NULL,
    time_ban INT NOT NULL, -- Set to current UNIX timestamp when creating
    time_unban INT NOT NULL,
    ban_category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    mod_note TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'banned' NOT NULL,
    unbanned_by INT DEFAULT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (user)
        REFERENCES users (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
        
    FOREIGN KEY (banned_by)
        REFERENCES users (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This continues to happen even if the tables consist of just a single field.

Comment: It seems like your issue is not reproducible. Your code works [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c09d46a87fcf283f279bc19500d7762).

Comment: Works fine for me... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01f91be817e0fb9722b032c135e0d0d4

Comment: Show the previous query in your.script? Or if there is none, show us how you are running the script. The previous query is most likely missing a semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

According to the font color, "user" looks like a reserved word in your system,
try using back ticks `` to escape it.